# Getting undefined from useQuery hook in Jest test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, react-query

I have a following `useQuery` hook usage:

```js
const { data: user, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['user', userId],
    queryFn: () =>
      UserApi.getUserById(userId)
        .then(({ data }) => data)
        .catch(() => {
          NotificationManager.error('Error with getting user with id: ' + userId, { icon: true });
        })
  });
```

This works fine in my component, but I have problems with tests:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';

import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import { UserApi } from '../../api';
import { render } from '../../config/test/root-render';
import useCurrentUserInfo from '../../hooks/useCurrentUserInfo';

import UserDetails from './UserDetails';

jest.mock('../../api/UserApi');
jest.mock('../../hooks/useCurrentUserInfo');
jest.mock('../../root/router', () => {
  return {
    useCurrentRoute: () => ({ params: { userId: 'userId' }, parent: { key: '' } }),
    generateUrlByKey: () => '1'
  };
});

function mockApi(userFiles, userStatus, userSecondaryStatus) {
  UserApi.getUserById = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
    new Promise((resolve) =>
      resolve({
        data: { userFiles: userFiles, general: { status: userSecondaryStatus}, userStatus: userStatus}
      })
    )
  );
}

function mockAndRender(userFiles, userStatus, userSecondaryStatus) {
  useCurrentUserInfo.mockReturnValue([{}]);
  mockApi(userFiles, userStatus, userSecondaryStatus);
  render(<UserDetails />);
}

describe('<UserDetails />', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    mockAndRender([1], 'Awarded', null)
  })
})
```

And as you can see I didn't mock `useQuery` hook, cause I don't need it. I have to mock api call instead of hook. Moreover, mock of my api call works as expected (I've checked and verified it with debugger), but `useQuery` is returning undefined. Does anybody has ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean the `data` returned by `userQuery` is `undefined`?

Comment: Partially you are right, `data` in `const { data: user, refetch } = useQuery(...)` is `undefined`, but `data` in `.then(({ data }) => data)` has a correct value that I provide in my mock API function in the test.

Answer (score 0):

So, after deep research, I've found the root of the problem. The code described above is correct. But the problem was in lines I did not provide in my question.

```js
expect(screen.getByTestId('username')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Method `getByTestId` is getting data faster than data is defined. After changing the code to this it works as expected:

```js
expect(await screen.findByTestId('username')).toBeInTheDocument();
```